# Why hyphenation patterns from hyph-ru.tex are not working in TeX?

Tags: hyphenation

If we use [ruhyphal.tex](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lzdmt43wkl7gajt/ruhyphal.tex?dl=1) from distribution, generation of format is OK:

```
tex -ini '\input plain \count255=128 \loop \lccode\count255=\count255 \advance\count255 by 1 \ifnum \count255<256 \repeat \input ruhyphal \dump'
```

But if we use [hyph-ru.tex](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gznlfllf7haq7l1/hyph-ru.tex?dl=1) from distribution, it fails:

```
iconv -f utf8 -t koi8-r hyph-ru.tex > ruhyph.tex
tex -ini '\input plain \count255=128 \loop \lccode\count255=\count255 \advance\count255 by 1 \ifnum \count255<256 \repeat \input ruhyph \dump'
```

```
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2016/Debian) (INITEX)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/base/plain.tex
Preloading the plain format: codes, registers, parameters, fonts, more fonts,
macros, math definitions, output routines, hyphenation
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyphen/hyphen.tex))
(./ruhyph.tex
! Nonletter.
l.4834 8-
         7
?
```

It is less probable that hyphenation file from distribution is broken.
So why TeX fails?

**EDIT**

What each of the files in the following list is for?

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/txt/hyph-ru.pat.txt
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/tex/hyph-ru.tex
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/txt/hyph-ru.lic.txt
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/loadhyph-ru.tex
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/ptex/hyph-ru.t2a.tex
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/txt/hyph-ru.chr.txt
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/patterns/txt/hyph-ru.hyp.txt
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message you've got is pretty clear: dash (-) is not a letter, and only letters are allowed in the hyphenation patterns.

So, what is a letter? When loading hyphenation patterns, TeX treats as letters those characters which have `\lccode` set. Actually, you already have to assign `\lccodes` to all the second half of the 8-bit encoding (otherwise all the cyrillic letters would fail to be recognized), so do the final step and add

```
\lccode`\-=`\-
```

somewhere in your command line. For example,

```
tex -ini '\input plain \lccode`\-=`\- \count255=128 \loop \lccode\count255=\count255 \advance\count255 by 1 \ifnum \count255<256 \repeat \input ruhyph \dump'
```

Comment: It was totally unexpected for me that dash can be used in hyphenation pattern! Which list of words leads to generation of such hyphenation pattern? I would like to remove this hyphenation pattern from hyph-ru.tex and as such would like to know hyphenation of which words I will be missing.

Comment: There are many of patterns that include dash. Just look into the hyphenation definition file. They actually forbid hyphenation of a word with dash in it (if I read them correctly).

Comment: If they forbid hyphenation of word with dash, why use them in hyphenation pattern in the first place? Do you know where to find the list of words from which `hyph-ru.tex` is produced? Please say which "hyphenation definition file" exactly you are talking about.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko hyph-ru.tex isn't meant for 8bit-pdftex, see the wrapper loadhyph-ru.tex (which also shows you how to setup the lccode). You can look in the file for some information regarding the sources, more information can be found here http://www.hyphenation.org/

Comment: @UlrikeFischer interesting... But what exactly are the peculiarities of non-8bit TeX vs. 8bit TeX that require totally different hyphenation patterns? And with which program patterns for non-8bit TeX are generated? (hyphenation patterns for 8bit TeX are generated with `patgen` program). Maybe this should be asked as a separate question?

Comment: The only difference between 8-bit TeX and non-8-bit TeX with respect to hyphenation patterns is just that, the encoding.  In both cases the patterns are loaded via `loadhyph-ru.tex` that sets up the `\lccode`’s.  The UTF-8 patterns have been converted from the 8-bit ones, so the characters are the same, only encoded differently.  For more details, see our article about `hyph-utf8`: http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb29-3/tb93miklavec.pdf

Comment: @SergeiGolovan Please cancel the edit - I edited the wrong post, sorry.